# Meteor.js: time-based server calls?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

We're trying to make an application that pairs users in a database every Wednesday and Friday. How is done in Meteor?

So in the server code I was thinking of putting this in a timedserver.js file

```
boolean hasMatched = false;
boolean isWednesday = false;
while(true){
   if (day != Wednesday) isWednesday = false;
   if (day == Wednesday){
        matchUsers()
        Wednesday = true;
     }

setTimeOut(5 HOURS)
}
```

Is this how it should be approached? I'm not sure how to have continually running server code. Where do we put this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose to use [Meteor.setInterval()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_setinterval) instead of using an infinite while-loop, and why not using an interval of 24 hours instead of 5?
Then you can check the weekday of the current date, e.g. with [moment.js](https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/moment), and if it's wednesday or friday, run your code, at best asynchronously and non-blocking the interval.

Answer (score 1):

I probably wouldn't use a while loop for something like this.

One package comes to mind though: [synced-cron](https://atmospherejs.com/percolatestudio/synced-cron). It looks like it uses ["Parsers"](http://bunkat.github.io/later/parsers.html#overview) and there is quite a bit flexibility there.

Something like this would probably work:

```
SyncedCron.add({
  name: 'Crunch some important numbers for the marketing department',
  schedule: function(parser) {
    // parser is a later.parse object
    return parser.text('every Wednesday');
  }, 
  job: function() {
    var matchedUsers = matchUsers();
    return matchedUsers;
  }
});
```

I've never uses this package, but I believe this code would fire every Wednesday.

Comment: Cool package, I didn't know it so far... but seems to be proper, 'cause published by the guys from Percolate Studio. I will have a deeper look into it the next days. Thanks for this hint.

Answer (score 0):

May be using [cron job](http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml) will be better solution?